# Linux Java and long titles

Tags: java, linux, swing, jframe

I have a `JFrame` where I want to `setTitle` with a text string. The title can be fairly long (50-80 characters). For years now if I resized the window, Java would just truncate my string and show whatever fit. Since I have the most important information (e.g. the patient name) at the beginning of the string, this worked very well.

With a recent version of Java there has been a change. Instead of truncating the string, it shows nothing. This happens in a Linux (Ubuntu) JVM. In Windows the truncated string is still shown. My version is 1.7.0_85, OpenJDK.

```
public class TestTitle {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame");
    // Add a window listner for close button
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    // This is an empty content area in the frame
    JLabel jlbempty = new JLabel("");
    jlbempty.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
    frame.getContentPane().add(jlbempty, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setTitle("Here is a long title with lots of text");
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

This will come up showing an empty title bar. When it is enlarged in the x direction, suddenly the text will appear.

My question is: can anyone else duplicate the problem, and can anything be done about it? (Set some environment variable or something similar?) Perhaps I need to file a bug report.

Comment: Please post a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) so that others can run and debug it.

Comment: I just tried on Ubuntu 14.04, with both JDK 1.8.0_60 and JDK 1.7.0_79 and both showed a truncated title.  Maybe it is not an issue with the JDK but with Unity configuration. I use gnome-fallback-session.

Comment: It is good that JDK 1.8.0_60 show a truncated title. It is fairly recently that the problem showed up - could be between 0_79 and 0_85. This is a plugin where the main program is still at 1.7, so I didn't want to use 1.8. When the main programs switches, I will switch as well. I have switched to 14.10, and I use Unity.

Comment: I have a zip file which contains a Netbeans project. It also contains a distribution folder with a jar file. My question is: where and how do I upload such a SSCCE?

Comment: The link to the SSCCE is https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rle6nfbz91qawx4/AABUpyXV6ai-UuroZpMdQP93a?dl=0 The file is TitleBar.zip

Comment: @IlanTal, post the code in the forum. The code would be about 5-10 lines of code 1) create a JFrame, 2) set the title, 3) make the frame visible. There is no need for a zip file.